# I dont understand why this code works (Codingbat Array2 tenRun)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

> For each multiple of 10 in the given array, change all the values following it to be that multiple of 10, until encountering another multiple of 10. So {2, 10, 3, 4, 20, 5} yields {2, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20}.

I don't understand why this works. In my mind the output for {1, 10, 2, 2} should be {1, 10, 10, 2}, because the for loop should only detect %10 == 0 once, and then loop back and not detect it the next time. Why does it do this more then once?

```
public int[] tenRun(int[] nums) {
   for (int i = 0; i < nums.length-1; i++) {
      if (nums[i] % 10 == 0) {
          if (nums[i+1] % 10 != 0) {
              nums[i+1] = nums[i];
          }
      }
   }
   return nums;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each iteration, whenever the condition, `nums[i] % 10 == 0` evaluates to `true` (i.e. `nums[i]` is a multiple of `10`), it checks if the next element is not a multiple of 10 i.e. `nums[i + 1] % 10 != 0` and if it is the case, it sets the next element to `nums[i]` which is a multiple of `10`. I hope, it helps you understand how it works. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tenRun(new int[] { 2, 10, 3, 4, 20, 5 })));
    }

    public static int[] tenRun(int[] nums) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
            if (nums[i] % 10 == 0) {
                if (nums[i + 1] % 10 != 0) {
                    nums[i + 1] = nums[i];
                }
            }
        }
        return nums;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20]
```

Comment: OOOH now I get it, I did not remember that the element gets updated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
public int[] tenRun(int[] nums) {
  for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
    if(nums[i]%10==0){
      for(int j=i+1;j<nums.length && nums[j]%10!=0;j++){
        nums[j]=nums[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return nums;
}
```

Comment: Please add some comment, explanation, tip, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop only loops `nums.length-1` times, and it looks at all the *overlapping pairs* of elements in the array: `nums[i]` (which I will call `a`) and `nums[i+1]` (which I will call `b`).

The for loop will only ever change `b`, and never `a`. It only checks if `a` is a multiple of 10. If it is, set `b` to `a`. Look at the last pair in the array, `b` here is the last element. Therefore, the last element *will* potentially be changed by the loop.

The loop will at some point look at `nums[1]` and `nums[2]`, and after setting `nums[2]` to 10, it now looks at the last pair, which is `nums[2]` (`a`) and `nums[3]` (`b`). Notice how `nums[2]` has just been set a value of 10, *so that*, `nums[3]` can be set to 10 as well.

On the other hand, the loop will never sets the *first* element, which is the `a` of the first pair. This is correct as it will not be after any multiples of 10.

Answer (score 0):

When you detect a multiple of 10, followed by a non-multiple of 10, your algorithm  updates the following value. On the next iteration of the loop you encounter this *updated* value. Given that this has to be a multiple of 10 now, the subsequent value is then updated.

If we consider the state of `i` and `nums` at the *start* of each iteration, we find:

```
0: 1, 10,  2,  2
1: 1, 10,  2,  2
2: 1, 10, 10,  2
```

So on that final iteration (the loop terminates when `i == 3`), `nums[2] == 10`, hence `nums[3]` is also set to `10`.